# Assets used in Matrix as Low Variable doesn't get updated

Tags: matrix, assets, low-variables

Can someone else who updated to latest Assets 201 try this on your install?
I have a Matrix as Low Variable and inside I have a column with Assets, that Assets doesn't get updated on submiting. Assets alone in LowVariable works fine.

EE 253, latest Matrix/LowVars/Assets

Thank you

Comment: You might want to update to EE 2.5.5 as well to eliminate a bug there.

Comment: Hey Anna, I just updated to 255 and the bug is still there :( As I can see the images does update the table, but they are not pulled in Matrix after the update. So if I update it again it writes empty cell. Thank you

Comment: I opened support request with both P&T and Low's https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/assets_field_used_in_matrix_as_a_low_variable_doesnt_pull_information_from_db

Comment: Same here with the latest versions of everything Assets and Low Variables not playing nice anymore.

Comment: Just an update that new Assets update 202 didn't fix this issues

Comment: Found the issue: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/assets_field_used_in_matrix_as_a_low_variable_doesnt_pull_information_from_db#reply_11076847

Comment: Please direct bug reports directly to developers - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a bug in how Assets was fetching data in this specific instance. Next release will fix this. (Credit goes to Low, by the way)